Why are Martingales the Objects to Look at in Banach Spaces/Understand their Geometry?
Perhaps I need to read some more, but could anyone provide basic intuition as to why (Banach valued) martingales are the right things to look at when performing vector valued analysis/understanding the geometry of Banach spaces? What is the relation between "fair games" (maybe this is a bit reductionist) and the geometry of a vector space? Does anyone have a brief history of this approach/who possibly thought of it first and some work explaining the motivations?
I can understand why one would be interested in Banach valued functions - it's a natural approach for understanding evolution equations (e.g. heat equation), but why martingales of all things?
Thank you!

Imagine the heat equation as describing a generalized (or aggregated) random walk, and the picture might become clearer.
